# Angular 2 Component property shadowing

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have declared one property called `foobar` in the Angular 2 `Foobar` component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-foobar',
  templateUrl: './foobar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foobar.component.css']
})
export class FoobarComponent implements OnInit {

  foobar= 'test';

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

then in `foobar.component.html` file I output that property like this:

```
<div>
   <br>
   {{foobar}} 
</div>
```

and it outputs word `test`, however, once I have added element with id `foobar`:

```
<div>
   <br>
   {{foobar}}
   <br>
   <input type="text" #foobar>
</div>
```

I'm no longer able to get value from the component and it outputs `[object HTMLInputElement]`, because it was shadowed by the input field id.

How can I get value from the component without changing component property name and input field id?

Comment: Components don't have variables, they have properties.

Comment: @torazaburo thank you, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<div>
    <br>
    {{ this['foobar'] }}
    <br>
    <input type="text" #foobar>
</div>
```

but it is not documented and may break in future releases

Answer (score 1):

Try with two-way databinding:

```
<div>
  <br />
  {{foobar}}
  <br />
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="foobar">
</div>`
```

To accomplish that you need the module:  **@angular/forms** in your package.json and don´t forget to import it to your app-module:

```
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
   declarations: [ ... ],
   imports: [
      FormsModule,
      ...
   ]
   ...
})
export class AppModule{ ... }
```